# How does this lick work harmonically?

Tags: harmony, chord-theory

Here is the lick (3:38 - 3:39).

He is playing it over a `F minor` chord. The key of the song is `Ab`. It looks like he just playing extentions of the `F minor chord`. What is a better way to explain this?

Comment: It would be a tad easier if you transcribed the part in question

Comment: sorry. the lick is Bb and Eb, C and F, Eb and Ab, F and Bb.

Comment: Are you asking about the part at 3:38 - 3:39?

Comment: yes thats the part im talking about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He's playing a pentatonic scale pattern, harmonized in fourths, which is a common device in jazz. Open fourths give an ambiguous sense of harmony even though, in this case, he never actually leaves the home key.

`Ab Major` = `Ab Bb C Db Eb F G` and an `F minor` chord, `F Ab C`, is the `vi` chord, consisting entirely of notes within the `Ab Major` scale.

The primary (upper) notes of the solo are `Eb F Ab Bb C Eb F Ab`, which is an `F minor pentatonic` (also `Ab major pentatonic`) scale, starting on `Eb`. By using the pentatonic scale, both `E natural` (the leading tone in `F minor`) and `G natural` (the leading tone in `Ab major`) are avoided, giving a sense of tonal ambiguity even though all of the pitches are within the key/scale. This is enhanced by starting on `Eb` rather than `F` or `Ab`.

Harmonizing the scale at the fourth below gives `Bb C Eb F *Ab* Bb C Eb`. Note that the pattern breaks at the `Ab`. This keeps the harmony within the pentatonic scale and avoids the `G natural` (`Ab` leading tone). This use of fourths also reinforces the tonal ambiguity while staying within the key.

This is a basic example of "quartal harmony".

The pianist McCoy Tyner, among others, is particularly well known for using quartal chord voicings. A clear example can be heard in the opening vamp on "My Favorite Things" from the album *Coltrane: Live at the Half Note*.

Answer (score 2):

He plays the following notes (disregard the rhythm values):

```
X: 1  
K: C
L: 1/4   
[_B,_E] [CF] [_E_A] [F_B] [_Ac] | [_B_e] [cf] [_e_a] [f_b] |
```

It is an (almost) constant interval moving up over the notes of F minor pentatonic (F Ab Bb C Eb). However, in this context I wouldn't call it "extension", but rather a passage, transition.